# Find a value, copy an offset but only to a point

Tags: excel, vba

In various places in column E of spreadsheet "Review" I have variables that start with the word "Sustainability:" (e.g., Sustainability: a, Sustainability:B"). Each time it finds one. I want it to copy the cell that is in the same row but two columns to the right. Then I want it to paste into a different sheet (SPSE Tran), starting at B63. Each time it pastes, the destination needs to offset by 1 row so it can paste down until it finds no more "Sustainability:". The code below is a start to this but I am stuck.

The second thing I need it to do (which I don't even know where to start) is to only iterate doing this until it finds a row that says "ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS". This leads into a new section that also includes "Sustainability:" but I don't want it to copy from there.

Thank you!

```
    Sub SubmitData()

    Dim RngA As Range
    Dim FirstAd As String
    Dim DestAd As Range
      With Sheets("Review").Range("E:E")
        Set RngA = .Find(What:="Sustainability:", lookat:=xlPart)
        Set DestAd = Range("B63")
        If Not RngA Is Nothing Then
            FirstAd = RngA.Address
            Do
                Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("SPSE Tran").Range(DestAd)
                Set RngA = .FindNext(RngA)
                Set DestAd = DestAd.Offset(0, 1)
            Loop While Not RngA Is Nothing And RngA.Address <> FirstAd
        End If
      End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "Only for Transitions", is that text going to be in column G when it finds the "Sustainability:" cells in column E? And then only copy the cells where "Only for Transitions" is found in those column G cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code revamped to use a filter instead of a find loop, and then it gets all the results and copies them to the destination at once:

```
Sub SubmitData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDest As Range
    Dim rngStop As Range

    With Sheets("SPSE Tran")
        Set rngDest = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
        If rngDest.Row < 63 Then Set rngDest = .Range("B63")
    End With

    Set ws = Sheets("Review")
    Set rngStop = ws.Columns("A").Find("ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS", , xlValues, xlPart)

    With ws.Range("E1:E" & rngStop.Row)
        .AutoFilter 1, "Sustainability:*"
        .Offset(1, 2).Copy rngDest
        .AutoFilter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it is working. What I mean by only for transitions is that, on the review tab, there is a line with the words "ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS" in column A. I want the code above (where it looks for sustainability) to only run until it hits that line. The exact row number that "ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS" appears on will vary because rows can be inserted above it.

Comment: I have updated the code for the ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS requirement

Comment: Hi, one question. Can you explain why the offset is (1,2). I understand the 2 as 2 columns over, but don't understand the 1 for the row, wouldn't that copy the next row down? (I know it doesn't but it seems like it should). Thanks!

Comment: The autofilter starts on the header row. So it goes 1 row down in order to not copy over the header row

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense. I just posted another question that is very similar to this. I was sure I could adapt your code but have failed for some reason. Just when I think I am getting this!

Answer (score 0):

How about (untested):

```
RngB = where you find "ONLY FOR TRANSITIONS"
RngBRow = RngB.Row
```

then change your `Loop While ..` to

```
Loop While Not RngA Is Nothing And RngA.Address <> FirstAd And RngA.Row < RngBRow
```